# Opening results returned by unix find with (g)vim

Tags: vim, gvim

I often find myself `find`ing files in a shell, and then wanting to edit all of them in a **single** gvim instance.

But the following: `find . -name foo -print0 | xargs -0 gvim` opens a gvim instance for every file found (`gvim 'find . -name foo'` doesn't work aswell).

How can I open all of them in a single instance? (no splits or tabs needed)

EDIT: I narrowed it down to simply running the command `gvim file1 file2` opens 2 instances. Can't find anything in gvim help on how to make it open one.

Comment: The command `gvim file1 file2` will open one instance of `gvim`. What makes you think it opens two?

Comment: it was something wrong with my .bashrc that made it not work. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vim `find . -name foo`

Comment: that works with vim but not with gvim

Comment: Try 'gvim -U NONE files'. This will not read initialization files, perhaps there is something that causes this behavior.

Comment: ah! it wasn't something with my .vimrc but you got me thinking and it was something related to my .bashrc. thanks!

Comment: @Gilles: I know that, and thanks for reminding :) I suggested this command to rule out the possibility that xargs executed gvim twice.